# Laravel 5 redirects back to home after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a page where users needs to login to click on a button, if they are not logged in they are taken to the login page to login. The problem is after the login they get redirected to home page. I would like them to be redirected back to the page they were before the login but can't get it to work.

The method of the login is still 100% standard. I have tried editing this function but with no luck.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to redirect the user to a different page instead of the /home, just define a

```
protected $redirectTo = 'your-different-route';  // i.e. '/admin'
```

at the top of your AuthController

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = 'admin/';
    ......
```

This should override the default route.
Anyway, in you wanna dig a bit deeper into the login system

```
return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

is the key. Looking up to the `intended` method (Illuminate\Routing\Redirector) you will find something like this

```
    public function intended($default = '/', $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)
    {
        $path = $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default);

        return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
    }
```

Then, you are injecting into the intended method  `$this->redirectPath()`, defined as

```
public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
            return $this->redirectPath;
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }
```

Basically, every time the user performs a login, the system checks if there's a different `intended` route, if not it uses the default one (/home). You can change the default redirect route into the very redirectPath() method, but care, this is part of the laravel framework, so every time laravel gets an update, you might lose your changes. A safer solution is, like I said few lines above, override the `redirect` in the AuthController (uploads and stuff won't affect the controller).

**EDIT**
If you instead want to set up a custom redirect route for each login, Laravel ships with a convenient way to accomplish that right out of the box, and, once again, we are going to use the `intended()` method. Wherever you redirect the user to the login page, let's say the `getLogin()` method, you need to change the default redirect, something like

```
return view('auth.login');
```

to

```
return Redirect::guest('auth.login') //assuming that auth.login is your login view
```

With this simple fix, you are still redirecting the user to the login page, but using the `guest()` method instead:

```
public function guest($path, $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $this->session->put('url.intended', $this->generator->full());

    return $this->to($path, $status, $headers, $secure);
}
```

Fairly straightforward, but, beside the standard redirect `to()`, it sets into `session` the `intended` variable equal to the current url BEFORE the actual redirection, i.e. the page where you wanna be redirected to.This is what is gonna save your day.
Last thing, within your `postLogin()` method, just set

```
return Redirect::intended('default-route');
```

You need to pass a default in case an intended location isn't provided in the session. Note that this is just a safety-plus, because by default, your `postLogin()` already has

```
redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

It uses by default `redirectPath()`, but now `Redirect::guest()` should provide an `intended` value.

Comment: Yea I do understand all this this but this answer doesn't redirect my user back to where he or she was before. That is my issue. I can change the route no problem but getting the user back to the same page is the problem

Comment: @master I do not get it. Why can't you redirect the user?

Comment: @master ok, i figured out what's might be your problem. The way I did show you would set the $redirectPath to every login attempt while you probably need a custom redirection that gets triggered only when the user is prompted to login within your specific page. Let me know if this is your case and I'll edit my answer accordingly to this need.

Comment: Sure, let me explain more. I have a web site that has multiple logins, or conditions where the sites asks a user to log in. So the login can't just go to a specific page, it need to go back where the user last was before the login. like redirect->back but like redirect->back->back thing is you don't get a method like that so no idea how to do it

Comment: @master Allright, now I get it. I'm gonna edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Redirect->back() method:

```
if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
{
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Although it's generally best to handle this in the Auth middleware.

More info can be found on the [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects).

Comment: This also doesn't work as this takes the user back to the login page after he has logged in...I need the user to go back to the page where he or she was before the login.

Answer (score 0):

please check [this](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/issues/403#issuecomment-462051464) solution you might need to add

```
  /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/player';

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
        return redirect()->route('homePlayer') ;
    }
```

in your LoginController.php